# Sitecore - not publishing media library

Tags: sitecore

We are using Sitecore 6.5 and have a multi-site Sitecore solution (with lots of library code we have inherited)

Publishing the Media Library by item from Staging to Production but we are not seeing the image on the web.

The images are in the web database and the path to the images in the web site is good.

Error we are getting when the file is requested (same in browser window address bar) is `http://domainname/error?aspxerrorpath=/~/media/OSS/Images/WaterAndWildlife/myimage.jpg.`

There is no media prefix in the web.config

Any idea?

....Looking into it now but site is going live tomorrow so help very appreciated! Help!!

Comment: Exactly what behavior are you seeing? Simply 404 for the media library items? Are the images blobs in the database or are they on the filesystem?

Comment: Please check a few things  1) In web.config <!--  MEDIA - MEDIA LINK PREFIX (which by default is "~/media") Default value: "" --> Setting. 2) The image path which you are referring to, can you browse to that directly in a browser window and see the image? 3) In your code if you are using  MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(field.MediaItem) then, make sure you get your hostname prefixed to that correctly. I ended up writing a custom function that gave the hostname.

Comment: They will be blobs on the db. Error we are getting when the file is requested (same in browser window) is http://websitedomainname/error?aspxerrorpath=/~/media/OSS/Images/WaterAndWildlife/myimage.jpg. There is no media prefix in the web.config

Comment: Shriroop - Why might we need to prefix it with the host name?

Comment: You are correct you shouldn't need to prefix it with hostname, but I also presumed that when I was working with media library on an email based project. Some how my images would render and give me the path "/~/media/somefolder/someimage.jpg" but would not render on the page. Adding the hostname prefix, fixed the issue. Point I am trying to make is fix the display issue on hand, you might get your images displaying and then fix the actually issue that is causing this problem to you.

Comment: Could it be a caching issue?  It sounds like publishing is working because you can see the items in the web database.  But maybe Sitecore is not clearing the cache on the delivery site(s).  Have you gone through all of the steps in the Scaling Guide?  Specifically, have you enabled EventQueues on BOTH environments (CM and CD's)?

Comment: You are getting the error page, so a 500 error occurred, which means the log file will contain the error details. Please post this info from the log.

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar problem when, in production, media files were not published which resulted in 404 errors.

**Solution:** The problem was that media files were not saved to the database because a file path was provided with the Sitecore media files while uploading.

So the images were saved on the file system instead of in the database. But based on our web.config configuration we were fetching images from the database.

If you are facing a similar issue, just download the media image, remove the file path, and save it. Then re-upload the same image, save and publish the image.

Hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One question, are these staging and production environments separate code files? if they are, what is the setting in your web.config for the settigns UploadAsFiles? because if that's true it will store them on server and the images will be on staging but not on prod. But usually if this setting is true and the files are getting stored in file system, specially in CM/CD environment it should push the physical files on publish as well, but sometime there might be other issues going on like permission etc..... and the files cant get to the destination.

```
 "<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false">"
```